# Stopping a object in java script canvas at specific point

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a circle and make it move on X axis in canvas. And I manage to stop for a few second at specific point and turn it's path on Y axis.
 Now I want to make it stop for a few seconds at some point in Y axis, and return to the point where it started on Y axis journey. 
I've tried multiple ways and it want work for me. I would really thankful if someone can help on this.

```
Java Script(Demo2.js)
```

```js
window.onload = init();

function init() {

  c = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 800, 500);
  ctx.fill();

  var x1 = 50;
  var y1 = 150;
  var SPEED = 2;
  var goRight = true;
  var count = 0;
  var stop = false;

  function updateStuff() {
    if (goRight == true && stop == false)

      x1 = x1 + SPEED;

    //if(x1 > 1000)
    //SPEED = SPEED * -1;

    //if(x1 < 1)
    //SPEED = SPEED * -1;

    if (count > 200)
      stop = true;
    if (count > 300) {
      stop = false;
      goRight = false;
    }

    if (goRight == false && stop == false) {
      y1 = y1 + 1;
    }

    function clear() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.rect(0, 0, 800, 500);
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawStuff() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x1, y1, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = "RED";
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function gameLoop() {
      count = count + 1;
      clear();
      updateStuff();
      drawStuff();
      setTimeout(gameLoop, 20)
    }
    gameLoop();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Would normally increment y1 exactly like your x1, that should get it to move on y axis

Comment: Yes the circle is moving on Y axis. But i want to stop it @ some point in Y axis and wait few seconds return to the start point where it turn Y axis form X axis.